# How to read files in two separate lists in a function based on a condition in R

Tags: r

Okay, I hope I manage to sum up what I need to achieve. I am running experiments in which I obtain data from two different source, with a date_time being the matching unifying variable. The data in the two separate sources have the same structure (in csv or txt). The distinction is in the filenames. I provide an example below:

```
list_of_files <- structure(
  list
  (
    solid_epoxy1_10 = data.frame(
      date_time = c("20/07/2022 13:46",
                    "20/07/2022 13:56",
                    "20/07/2022 14:06"),
      frequency = c("30000",
                    "31000",
                    "32000"),
      index = c("1", "2", "3")
    ),
    solid_otherpaint_20 = data.frame(
      date_time = c("20/07/2022 13:10",
                    "20/07/2022 13:20",
                    "20/07/2022 14:30"),
      frequency = c("20000",
                    "21000",
                    "22000"),
      index = c("1", "2", "3")
    ),
    water_epoxy1_10 = data.frame(
      date_time = c("20/07/2022 13:46",
                    "20/07/2022 13:56",
                    "20/07/2022 14:06"),
      temperature = c("22.3",
                      "22.6",
                      "22.5")
    ),
    water_otherpaint_20 = data.frame(
      date_time = c("20/07/2022 13:10",
                    "20/07/2022 13:20",
                    "20/07/2022 14:30"),
      temperature = c("24.5",
                      "24.6",
                      "24.8")
    )
  )
)
```

First I want to read the data files in two separate lists. One that contains the keyword "solid" in the file name, and the other one that contains "water".
Then I need to create a new columns from the filename in each data frame that will be separated by "_" (e.g paint = "epox1", thickness = "10"), by which I could do an inner join by the date_time column, paint, thickness,etc. Basically what I struggle so far is to create a function that loads that files in two separate lists. This is what I've tried so far

```
load_files <-
  function(list_of_files) {
    all.files.board <- list()
    all.files.temp <- list()
    for (i in 1:length(list_of_files))
    {
      if (exists("board")) {
        all.files.board[[i]] = fread(list_of_files[i])
      }
      else{
        all.files.temp[[i]] = fread(list_of_files[i])
      }
      return(list(all.files.board, all.files.temp))
    }
  }
```

But it doesn't do what I need it. I hope I made it as clear as possible. I'm pretty comfortable with the tidyverse package but writing still a newbie in writing custom functions. Any ideas welcomed.

Comment: Your function returns the moment it reaches `return()` , you probably want to move it by one `}` so it wouldn't break out of your for-loop. Also, did you miss some changes when you prepared this reprex? If your `fread()` is `data.table::fread()`, I don't think it can handle list as an input/file/text param. By any chance, did you mean  `as.data.table(list_of_files[i])`? And that approach leaves holes in your output lists.

Comment: Thanks for the comment. I guess it's not the greatest reprex as I kept the `data.table::fread()` from my original code that works with actual numerical data. Should I just the col_types in the example data? Moving the `return()` by one `}` reads all files in the list, which is an improvement, as at least now all files in the list are read. Sorry, if anything is unclear, still struggling with the right terminology.

Answer (score 0):

Regarding question in the title -

- first issue, calling `return()` too early and thus breaking a for-loop, was already mentioned in comments and that should be sorted.
- next one is condition itself, `if (exists("board")){}` checks if there is an object called `board`; in provided sample it would evaluate to `TRUE` only if something was assigned to global `board` object before calling `load_files()` function and it would evaluate to `FALSE` only if there were no such assignment or `board` was explicitly removed. I.e. with
  `board <- "something"; dataframes <- load_files(file_list)` that check will be `TRUE` while with
  `rm(board); dataframes <- load_files(file_list)` it will be `FALSE`, there's nothing in function itself that would change the "existance" of `board`, so the result is actually determined before calling the function.

If core of the question is about joining 2 somewhat different datasets and splitting result by groups, I'd just drop loops, conditions and most of involved lists and would go with something like this with Tidyverse:

```r
library(fs)
library(readr)
library(stringr)
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

# prepare input files for sample ------------------------------------------

sample_dfs <- structure(
  list
  (
    solid_epoxy1_10 = data.frame(
      date_time = c("20/07/2022 13:46", "20/07/2022 13:56", "20/07/2022 14:06"),
      frequency = c("30000", "31000", "32000"),
      index = c("1", "2", "3")
    ),
    solid_otherpaint_20 = data.frame(
      date_time = c("20/07/2022 13:10", "20/07/2022 13:20", "20/07/2022 14:30"),
      frequency = c("20000", "21000", "22000"),
      index = c("1", "2", "3")
    ),
    water_epoxy1_10 = data.frame(
      date_time = c("20/07/2022 13:46", "20/07/2022 13:56", "20/07/2022 14:06"),
      temperature = c("22.3", "22.6", "22.5")
    ),
    water_otherpaint_20 = data.frame(
      date_time = c("20/07/2022 13:10", "20/07/2022 13:20", "20/07/2022 14:30"),
      temperature = c("24.5", "24.6", "24.8")
    )
  )
)


tmp_path <- file_temp("reprex")
dir_create(tmp_path)

sample_filenames <- str_glue("{1:length(sample_dfs)}_{names(sample_dfs)}.csv")

for (i in seq_along(sample_dfs)) {
  write_csv(sample_dfs[[i]], path(tmp_path, sample_filenames[i]))
}
dir_ls(tmp_path, type = "file")
#> Temp/RtmpqUoct8/reprex5cc517f177b/1_solid_epoxy1_10.csv
#> Temp/RtmpqUoct8/reprex5cc517f177b/2_solid_otherpaint_20.csv
#> Temp/RtmpqUoct8/reprex5cc517f177b/3_water_epoxy1_10.csv
#> Temp/RtmpqUoct8/reprex5cc517f177b/4_water_otherpaint_20.csv


# read files --------------------------------------------------------------

t_solid <- dir_ls(tmp_path, glob = "*solid*.csv", type = "file") %>%
  read_csv(id = "filename") %>%
  extract(filename, c("paint", "thickness"), "_([^_]+)_(\\d+)\\.csv")
t_solid
#> # A tibble: 6 × 5
#>   paint      thickness date_time        frequency index
#>   <chr>      <chr>     <chr>                <dbl> <dbl>
#> 1 epoxy1     10        20/07/2022 13:46     30000     1
#> 2 epoxy1     10        20/07/2022 13:56     31000     2
#> 3 epoxy1     10        20/07/2022 14:06     32000     3
#> 4 otherpaint 20        20/07/2022 13:10     20000     1
#> 5 otherpaint 20        20/07/2022 13:20     21000     2
#> 6 otherpaint 20        20/07/2022 14:30     22000     3

t_water <- dir_ls(tmp_path, glob = "*water*.csv", type = "file") %>%
  read_csv(id = "filename") %>%
  extract(filename, c("paint", "thickness"), "_([^_]+)_(\\d+)\\.csv")
t_water
#> # A tibble: 6 × 4
#>   paint      thickness date_time        temperature
#>   <chr>      <chr>     <chr>                  <dbl>
#> 1 epoxy1     10        20/07/2022 13:46        22.3
#> 2 epoxy1     10        20/07/2022 13:56        22.6
#> 3 epoxy1     10        20/07/2022 14:06        22.5
#> 4 otherpaint 20        20/07/2022 13:10        24.5
#> 5 otherpaint 20        20/07/2022 13:20        24.6
#> 6 otherpaint 20        20/07/2022 14:30        24.8

# or implement as a function ----------------------------------------------

load_files <- function(csv_path, glob = "*.csv") {
  return(
    dir_ls(csv_path, glob = glob, type = "file") %>%
      # store filenames in filename column
      read_csv(id = "filename", show_col_types = FALSE) %>%
      # extract each regex group to its own column
      extract(filename, c("paint", "thickness"), "_([^_]+)_(\\d+)\\.csv"))
}


# join / group / split ----------------------------------------------------

t_solid <- load_files(tmp_path, "*solid*.csv")
t_water <- load_files(tmp_path, "*water*.csv")

# either join by multiple columns or select only required cols 
# to avoid x.* & y.* columns in result
inner_join(t_solid, t_water, by = c("date_time", "paint", "thickness")) %>% 
  group_by(paint) %>% 
  group_split()
```

Final result as a list of tibbles:

```
#> <list_of<
#>   tbl_df<
#>     paint      : character
#>     thickness  : character
#>     date_time  : character
#>     frequency  : double
#>     index      : double
#>     temperature: double
#>   >
#> >[2]>
#> [[1]]
#> # A tibble: 3 × 6
#>   paint  thickness date_time        frequency index temperature
#>   <chr>  <chr>     <chr>                <dbl> <dbl>       <dbl>
#> 1 epoxy1 10        20/07/2022 13:46     30000     1        22.3
#> 2 epoxy1 10        20/07/2022 13:56     31000     2        22.6
#> 3 epoxy1 10        20/07/2022 14:06     32000     3        22.5
#> 
#> [[2]]
#> # A tibble: 3 × 6
#>   paint      thickness date_time        frequency index temperature
#>   <chr>      <chr>     <chr>                <dbl> <dbl>       <dbl>
#> 1 otherpaint 20        20/07/2022 13:10     20000     1        24.5
#> 2 otherpaint 20        20/07/2022 13:20     21000     2        24.6
#> 3 otherpaint 20        20/07/2022 14:30     22000     3        24.8
```